# If $G'(s)=G(s0^{|s|})$ and $G$ is a PRNG, is $G'$ necessarily a PRNG?

Tags: random-number-generator

I argue it is because there should be no more correlation between the outputs $G(s0^{|s|})$ than between the outputs $G(s)$. Thus we can say the $G'(s)$ is a PRNG that satisfies $|G'(s)| \geq 4|s|$. If we let $s' = s0^{|s|}$ and denote the set of all $s'$ by $S'$, then $s'$ should be chosen uniformly at random from $S'$. Since, as I stated there should be no correlation between $G'(s')$ for any $s'$, then effectively we are only increasing the expansion factor $l$.

Disagree? Please tell me why.

Comment: I attempted the same editing, but wondered if $s0$ is meant to be $s_0$, or something else; and in either case those come from nowhere and I fail to parse the question.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose g is a PRNG. $\:$ Define G by the following pseudocode:

```
def G(w):
 m = length(w)
 n = ceiling(m/2)
 set x equal to the n leftmost bits of w
 set y equal to the m-n rightmost bits of w
 z = concatenate(g(x),y)
 output z
```

In this case, G is a PRNG and G' is not a PRNG.

Comment: The way you wrote this was not clear. If I understand you correctly you mean to say: "Let G(s) be a PRNG. Then where $s = s_1, \dots ,s_n$ define $G'(s) = G(s_1, \dots ,s_{n/2})||(s_{(n/2)+1, \dots, s_n)$, where $||$ denotes the concatenation. In this case G'(s) is not a PRNG."